# Поиск символа в строке Java

Tags: java, html, строки

Есть такая строка

```html
<div class="emet_index" data-placeholder="current">138,05</div>
```

Как найти и вывести цифры из этой строки?  любым способом.
Конечно лучше не сложным.
Данная строка  не повторяется.

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Именно из этой строки или же строка может быть другой? Насколько другой? Или же цифры надо вытащить из произвольного тега `div`? Нужна строка (`String`) или число (`double`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если вы берете эту строку из HTML, то [JSOUP](http://jsoup.org/) (или другой парсер) вам в помощь. Находите нужный элемент и берете его содержимое методом `text()`

И не ведитесь на советы тех, кто предлагает использовать регулярные выражения для решения этой задачи.

**Дополнено**

Пример:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.*;
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Загружаем в парсер страницу с указанного URL (есть методы,
        // которыми можно взять страницу из переменной или файла)
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://site.ru/page").get();
        // Выбираем нужные элементы согласно CSS-селектору (".emet_index"),
        // берем их текст и выводим в консоль
        System.out.print(doc.select(".emet_index").text());
    }
}
```

API *JSOUP* очень похоже на *jQuery*

Comment: А через jsoup пример по данному вопросу можно? реально запарился искать. Вывести всю страницу то я осилил а вот поиск в ней уже проблематичней. Читал документацию и озадачился.

Comment: @DevilScream Вроде бы ничего сложного. Дополнил ответ примером. Сначала загружается страница (из сети или из файла), потом выбираются нужные элементы методом `select()`, аргументом которого является CSS-селектор, потом у элемента берется текстовое содержимое.

Comment: Ты крут чувак можно твой контакт? почта/вк/скайп/очень выручил. Реально. я в шоке столько мотался а тут лве строчки/ ты крут/

Comment: @DevilScream примеры даже на этом подсайте по тегу [tag:jsoup] можно поискать

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант через простой SubString

```
   String myStr = "<div class=\"emet_index\" data-placeholder=\"current\">138,05</div>";
   String sec = myStr.substring(myStr.indexOf(">") + 1, myStr.indexOf("</"));
   System.out.println(sec);
```

Answer (score 2):

Я бы воспользовался `replaceAll` и регулярным выражением

```
String s = "<div class=\"emet_index\" data-placeholder=\"current\">138,05</div>";

String str = s.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
```

Если нужна запятая — модифицировать также не трудно.

Comment: Не надо использовать регулярки при парсинге HTML!

Comment: Возможно из-за своей неопытности посоветовал данный способ, но я уверен что в некоторых случаях его можно применить. Хотя при тестировании api, признаюсь, парсил json-simple

Comment: RegExp несомненно полезная штука и надо их знать и уметь пользоваться. НО! Для парсинга HTML это совершенно не подходит. Он слишком сложен, чтобы учесть все нюансы.